# Using datediff from 2 joined tables

Tags: php, sql, laravel, date

I'd like to get the difference between two dates on two tables. The uploads.published_at compared to the completed_guides.created_at

I keep getting an error which says:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'datediff' (SQL: select users.*,completed_guides.created_at as completed_at,uploads.published_at,datediff(HOUR, published_at, completed_at) from `users` inner join `uploads` on `users`.`id` = `uploads`.`user_id` inner join `completed_guides` on `uploads`.`id` = `completed_guides`.`upload_id` where `completed_guides`.`upload_id` = 2839 limit 10)
```

Here is my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$select = [
    'users.*',
    'completed_guides.created_at as completed_at',
    'uploads.published_at',
    'datediff(HOUR, published_at, completed_at) as date_diff'
];

return User::select(DB::raw(join(',', $select)))
    ->join('uploads', 'users.id', '=', 'uploads.user_id')
    ->join('completed_guides', 'uploads.id', '=', 'completed_guides.upload_id')
    ->where('completed_guides.upload_id', $this->id)
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel Query Builder's [`whereRaw()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereRaw) like this:

```
return User::select(DB::raw(join(',', $select)))
            ->join('uploads', 'users.id', '=', 'uploads.user_id')
            ->join('completed_guides', 'uploads.id', '=', 'completed_guides.upload_id')
            ->where('completed_guides.upload_id', $this->id)
            ->whereRaw('datediff(uploads.published_at, completed_guides.completed_at) as date_diff')
            ->take(10)
            ->get();
```

To set the format of date you can use SQL method - `date_format(date, format)` like this:

```
->select(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(date_diff, '%b %d %Y %h:%i %p') as formatted_date_diff"));
```

> See more about [SQL Date Format](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Managed to get it working, needed to remove the `HOUR` parameter. Now it returns 0 as in 0 days difference, is it possible to return in `Y-m-d H:i` format?

Comment: You can use `DATE_FORMAT(date,format)` method of sql, try this. I've removed `HOUR` param from my answer!

Comment: @BenShepherd - I've updated my answer, please have a look!

Answer (score 0):

The one with units, is [timestampdiff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff), not datediff.

```
timestampdiff(HOUR, published_at, completed_at) as date_diff
```